# What is the equation for the number of integer solutions of $n$ for $n^2\equiv -1\pmod m$ where $0≤n<m$, given $m$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I can’t work out how to find the equation for the number of integer solutions of $n$ for $n^2\equiv -1\pmod m$ for any $m$ where $0≤n < m$.

The number of solutions, when non-zero, seems to be always of the form $2^k$ but that’s about all I can work out. Here’s a Desmos graph where I’ve brute forced some of the values just to see what the function looks like and I can’t see any patterns: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/r8uhdmhzzf

Does anyone know of a way I could go about solving this?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144810/discussion-on-question-by-edward-green-what-is-the-equation-for-the-number-of-in); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x$ is prime at least 3, then the multiplicative group is $(\mathbb{Z}/x\mathbb{Z})^\times$ is cyclic of size $x-1$, which means it has two solutions iff $x \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

If $x$ is a power of 2 like $2^k$ at least 8, then the multiplicative group is $(\mathbb{Z}/2^k\mathbb{Z})^\times$, congruent to a cyclic group of size 2 times a cyclic group of size $2^{k-2}$. So there's no solution.

If $x$ is some other prime power $p^k$, then the mult group is cyclic of size $p^k - p^{k-1}$, which is divisible by 4 iff $p - 1$ is (meaning, 2 solutions iff $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$).

If $x$ has prime factorization $\prod p_i^{k_i}$, then we use CRT to find the structure of the multiplicative group (and number of solutions to your equation). For example, $x = 3^25^2$ gives no solution because $\varphi(9) = 6$ and $C_6$ gives no solution, but $x = 5^2 \times 13$ has 4 solutions since $C_{20}$ has 2 solutions and $C_{12}$ has 2 solutions. And yeah, number of solutions would always be power of 2.

So in total, (assuming $x \ge 3$) it has solution iff $x = 2^{k_0}\prod p_i^{k_i}$ where $k_0 \le 1$ and $p_i \equiv 1 \pmod 4$. Number of them is $2^{\# \text{ non-2 primes}}$.

Comment: 10 has no solutions but it’s of the form $x=2^{k_0}\prod p_i^{k_i}$ where $k_0=1$ and $p_0=5\equiv1\pmod4$. The number of solutions according to that last statement should be 2, no?

Comment: @EdwardGreen $n^2 \equiv -1 \pmod{10}$ should have two solutions $n = 3$ and $n = 7$?

Comment: Ah. I don’t know what on Earth I was doing to manage to not get any solutions!